# ASP.Net uploading an image for a users avatar

Tags: asp.net, image

I dragged a file upload control to my Form, and I want to save the "image" the user chooses to an object[] Array so I can then save it.

I only need to know how to "grab" the image the user selects and save it as a byte[] array.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use the fileupload.SaveAs Method

```
if(myFileUpload.HasFile)
{
   myFileUpload.SaveAs(filenmae); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you not consider outsourcing to [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/), like in SO ?

Comment: I really despise Gravatar. :D